# "library.exe has stopped working" - Codeblocks

Tags: c++

I am currently working on a library project. In this program, to search a book, a function **search_book()** is called which further calls either **search_book_by_name()** or **search_book_by_acc()**. All the information about the books is stored in a binary file **BOOKS.dat**

```
class BOOK
{
public:
    void display_data();
    std::string copies;
    std::string price;
    std::string shelf;
    std::string row;
    std::string book_name;
    std::string author_name;
    std::string publisher;
    std::string acc_no;
};
void search_book()
{
    char ch;
    system("cls");
    box();       //for creating a rectangular boundry
    gotoxy(30,17);
    std::cout<<"1. Search by Name";
    gotoxy(30,19);
    std::cout<<"2. Search by Acc No";
    gotoxy(25,23);
    std::cout<<"Enter your choice: ";
    std::cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {
        case '1':   search_book_by_name();
                    break;
        case '2':   search_book_by_acc();
                    break;
        default:    std::cout<<"Invalid Case!";

    }
}
void search_book_by_name()
{
BOOK obj;
std::fstream f;
std::string searched_book;
system("cls");
box();           //for creating an box-like boundry
gotoxy(30,17);
std::cout<<"Enter name of the book: ";
std::getline(std::cin, searched_book);
f.open("BOOKS.dat",std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if(!f)
{
    std::cout<<"File opening error!";
    exit(0);
}
while(f.read((char *)&obj, sizeof(obj)))
{
    if(searched_book.compare(obj.book_name)==0)
    {
        obj.display_data();
    }
}
}

void search_book_by_acc()
{
int task=0;
std::fstream f;
std::string searched_acc;
BOOK obj;
system("cls");
box();
gotoxy(30,17);
std::cout<<"Enter Acc. No of book: ";
std::getline(std::cin, searched_acc);
f.open("BOOKS.dat",std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
while(f.read((char *)&obj, sizeof(obj)))
{
    if(searched_acc.compare(obj.acc_no)==0)
    {
        task=1;
        obj.display_data();
    }
}
if(task!=1)
    std::cout<<"Book not found!";
}
void BOOK::display_data()
{
system("cls");
box();
gotoxy(35,7);
std::cout<<"Book: "<<book_name;
gotoxy(35,8);
std::cout<<"Author/Writer: "<<author_name;
gotoxy(35,9);
std::cout<<"Publisher: "<<publisher;
gotoxy(35,10);
std::cout<<"Acc No: "<<acc_no;
gotoxy(35,11);
std::cout<<"Copies: "<<copies;
gotoxy(35,12);
std::cout<<"Price: "<<price;
gotoxy(35,13);
std::cout<<"Shelf: "<<shelf;
gotoxy(35,14);
std::cout<<"Rows: "<<row;
}
```

In the functions **search_book_by_name()** and **search_book_by_acc()** , the control is not reaching the while loop and suddenly a popup appears "**library.exe has stopped working**". 
I am not able to find any error there. I will be glad if someone can clear things up. Thanks!

Comment: You can't store `std::string`s like that. Read about *serialization* or use a text file.

Comment: But there was no error/problem occuring while storing the strings like that to the file. Its only happening during reading the file

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase: if you write`std::string`s like that, reading them back will give you invalid objects.

Comment: ok then how should I correct it? should i replace std::string with character array?